# Posix way to open socket descriptor in shell

Tags: shell, posix

In `bash`, we can use [file descriptors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor) in order to (try to) open [socket descriptors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_socket), as follow:

```
exec 3<>/dev/prot/host/port
```

where:

- `prot` can be `tcp` or `udp`;
- `host` can be a valid hostname or Internet address;
- `port` can be an integer port number or service name.

This is just an example and any redirection can be used
(E.G. `printf "%s" "${payload}" >"/dev/udp/${host}/${port}"`).
This is true *at least* starting from `bash v4+`.

Someone else already asked to accomplish the very same thing without a bash built-in;
I already found and tried other solutions, including (but not limited to):

- `nc`/`netcat`/`nmap`/`tcping` (or similar), in order to "scan" (local or remote) ports (some of those will not be able to receive payloads);
- `netstat`/`ss` (or similar), in order to know LISTEN-state (local) ports (and cannot send nor receive any payload);

Among the others, `nc` could be considered the most portable solution for this task even though (at least in my understandings) it should not be in [coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/); while solutions as `ss` cannot be considered valid for this task because they cannot "scan" another host and cannot send nor receive payloads;
Anyway, it happened to me to find some environment where `nc` was not installed.

I can't assume other interpreters are installed (E.G. `python`, `perl`, etc.);
I can't assume compilers are installed.

Finally, as you already guessed, the question:
**There is some posix-way, using anything but a shell, to accomplish a full connection?**

In other words, there is a portable way to make use of connections?

Comment: As far as I know, network sockets are *entirely* undefined by POSIX.

Comment: @chepner As stated [here](http://www.openss7.org/papers/strsock/sockimp.pdf), among various standards, there is a standard defined by POSIX on Network Sockets.  
Plus, in the POSIX Programmer's Manual is described `connect()` as system call (you can use `man connect` to read it) which clearly makes use of Network Sockets.
Plus#2, in the POSIX Programmer's Manual is described `socket()` which return a file descriptor (you can use `man socket` to read it).
The two of them are conforming to POSIX.1-2001 and POSIX.1-2008.

Comment: Network sockets are just one kind of socket; POSIX provides for general socket support, but doesn't mandate support for internet sockets (which are the kind you are asking about). See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_socket.h.html.

Comment: @chepner Please, help me understand. I don't need arguing on who is right or not...
The lib you linked same the same I provided previously.
In [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_socket#Definition), Network Socket is actually called `Internet Socket`, divided in 3 types.
Furthermore, I am not searching a way to write my own code, because as I wrote in my question, I can't assume compilers are available.
If the problem is, as you said, POSIX doesn't provide a description of Network Socket, there aren't issues because it does.
I'm searching a portable way of doing it in shell.

Comment: I'm not sure I can be clearer. "Portable" means that there is some established standard that different implementations agree to follow. No such standard exists for network sockets, so there is no "portable" way to do it. It depends entirely on what your OS or on what additional libraries you install.

Comment: @ingroxd Did you ever manage to find an answer to this question?

Comment: @TendersMcChiken No mate, at last I used nc, sticking with options that are valid either for traditional nc, openbsd nc and busybox nc, for portability's sake (options -l, -p, -w and -i only).
Usually you do not need to check where nc lays, but I advise you to do so and set a proper alias/var to call it.